# What is the time frame for moving to Aus after being approved for Visa 476 (skilled-recognised graduate visa)?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, australia

You have to apply for Visa 476 within 2 years of graduating from university but the processing times as shown on the [website](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/skilled-recognition-graduate-476#Overview) are:

- 75% of applications: 15 months
- 90% of applications: 17 months

So given the long wait my plan would be to do a graduate scheme in the UK (after I earn my Masters degree) and apply during it for the visa. However, most grad schemes are 2 years long so if my visa got accepted very quickly this wouldn't be ideal if I had to quit that midway through and move across to Aus shortly after approval.

So when you're approved what is the time frame in which you must move to Australia?

I'm from the UK, age 22 and will be graduating with an MEng just for some info.

Comment: As you have to be a qualified graduate to receive the visa, then I doubt they would allow you to apply before you have graduated (as you could drop out or fail graduation).

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Sorry if it was unclear, "graduate scheme" refers to a job scheme open to recent graduates. So, at the point of applying I would already have my Masters degree and currently be working for a company as part of their grad scheme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the starting date of a Recognised Graduate visa in Australia?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/when-is-the-starting-date-of-a-recognised-graduate-visa-in-australia)

Comment: @Traveller thanks for the link, that's useful. What I am really look for is a rough estimate of when this "enter by date" will be in relation to visa approval? e.g. approx. 1 month? 1 year?

Comment: @FEA42 In common with most visa applications I think you’ll be able to input your intended entry date when you apply, but I can’t find official confirmation of that right now for this particular visa.